# CSS - disabling a menu animation

Tags: css, wordpress, animation, wordpress-theming, css-animations

Just as a quick overview - I have purchased a theme for WordPress that has custom in-built animations for it's main menu (starts off large and transparent, and then on scroll, it becomes thinner with a solid colour background).

I've been trying for the past few days to simply set the scroll menu as the permanent menu and get rid of the animation, but I'm not having all that much luck with it, so any help would be really appreciated.

Css:

/* 2. Header
===============================================================*/

```
.wsmenucontainer header.topheader {
    background: #222;
}
.wsmenucontainer header.topheader {
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0 12rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wsmenucontainer header.topheader .header-image {
    background: #222;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.wsmenucontainer header.topheader .header-image img {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
header.topheader.scroll {
    background: #222;
    padding: 0;
}
header.topheader.scroll .header-image img {
    opacity: 0;
}
.noHeadImage  header.topheader {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    background:transparent;
}
.noHeadImage .header-image {
    display:none;
}
.noHeadImage header.topheader.scroll {
    background: #222;
    padding: 0;
}
main section {
    padding: 8rem 0;
}
main section#single-class{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jordy i help you, can you provide a Theme preview link?

Comment: Sure thing, it's here: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/evnt-event-conference-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/16996096?_ga=2.215963733.337054837.1559709588-2132234528.1559709588

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove or comment transition css. Hope it gelps

```
.wsmenucontainer header.topheader {
left: 0;
padding: 1rem 0 12rem;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
```

//comment this area to remove transition

```
/* transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease; */
```

}

```
.wsmenucontainer header.topheader .header-image img {
left: 0;
opacity: 0.5;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
```

//comment this area to remove image transition

```
/* transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease; */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, you can add a custom css in your theme (css custom area) or via plugin (https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/)
Your custom code:

```
.wsmenucontainer header.topheader{
  transition: none; */
    -moz-transition: none;
    /* -webkit-transition: none; */
    -o-transition: none;
}
```